# What is the difference between cluster computing and parallel computing?

Tags: server, parallel-processing, cloud

I have a big computational problem. Parallel computing breaks it down and shares with other processors and all the processors compute the instructions simulateously.

Cluster computing is like a cluster of processors and they do the same but one cluster acts as one single processor.

Is it right?
Can someone explain?

I searched the internet but couldn't find anything clear. Its all the same thing

Comment: "Cluster computing" is generally just parallel computing on clusters. Nothing more. I would argue that there is no such thing as cluster computing but just distributed computing and parallel computing. Not all parallel computation are distributed : a parallel computation on your mainstream PC is not distributed. Distributed computation are generally parallel since it does not make much sense to use multiple computing nodes so to do the work sequentially. That being said, it is sometimes not the main goal (eg. concurrency).

Comment: The main problem in your definition is the term "processor" which have several incompatible definitions. For some people, a processor is a microprocessor (relatively new meaning), while for some other it is a core (old meaning) or anything that can execute a thread (eg. hardware thread). It was not a problem before the rise of the multicore era, but now it is. I think you should first set a definition for it.

Answer (score 0):

Computing can be parallelized on different levels. And to start with, we need to go deeper than definitions of "processor" and "cluster" allow us.

Let's start with parallel computing. Parallel computing is a type of computation in which many calculations or processes are carried out simultaneously.

Ok, we somehow adopted our algorithm to be calculated in a parallel manner. But what hardware allows us to achieve this? A parallel computer requires:

- One or more CPUs. CPU can have multiple cores. Each core can do some calculations.
- Memory. Memory can be different. Varying from smaller and faster to bigger and slower: registers, L1-L4 caches, RAM, disk storage, network file system. Memory is a crucial part of a parallel computer because, without communication and data sharing, computational units can't work together.

[image]

Perfect parallel computer has memory that is uniformly accessible by all computational units. But in our real world, memory is usually a bottleneck preventing us from utilizing full computation power.

To exchange information between computational units, there are multiple patterns:

- One to All
- All to One
- All to All
- All reduce
- All scatter

Depending on what task we need to solve, we use different number on computation units.

Sometimes we can use even a **single core** to get some kind of parallel computing. This is called Data Level Parallelism, and one of its examples is Single Instruction Multiple Data (SIMD for short). Most of modern CPU cores can perform 8 simultaneous operations by applying a single instruction to 8 different pieces of data.

But when we need more power, we use **multiple cores**. On this scale, another type of parallelism comes to the stage: Single Program Multiple Data (SPMD) and it's subtype: Shared Memory Parallelism. The most common example of this is Fork Join model. Master thread creates multiple threads that share some workload (fork), and when this thread completes their work, control goes back to master (join).

[image]

Ok. But what if we need more computational power? Number of processing units per one computer is limited (single compute node). And to break this limit, we can use more compute nodes. Such a set of computers working together is called a **cluster**. In a cluster, all nodes don't share a single namespace for all memory. That's how we moved from Shared Memory Parallelism to Distributed Memory Parallelism. This way, we get more throughput at the cost of latency. Because the overhead of communication becomes higher.

I hope now you better understand that cluster computing is just one of the approaches aimed at achieving parallelism on a larger scale. If you have any other questions or something is still unclear, don't hesitate to leave your questions/comments, and I'll try to extend this answer or provide some links.